# How to retrieve earlier version of AWS SSM password?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I use the AWS parameter store like so `aws ssm get-parameters --names WINDOWS_PASSWORD --with-decryption --query Parameters[0].Value --output text`, but sometimes I need the earlier previous of the password when it rotates.

I don't understand for example how to retrieve version 1 of the password with the CLI, as opposed to say the latest version 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you would just **append version to the name**:

For example, to get the first version:

```
aws ssm get-parameters --names WINDOWS_PASSWORD:1 --with-decryption --query Parameters[0].Value --output text
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with below

```
aws ssm get-parameter-history \
    --name "MyParameter"
```

Answer (score 0):

use below command
aws ssm get-parameters --names : --with-decryption --query Parameters[0].Value --output text